# WebRTC PeerJS Text Chat - Connect to multiple peerID at the same time

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

Hi friends I have been working on to connect to multiple peer id for text chat when i connect to single peer alone it is working

but i am getting problem on connecting multiple peerid at the same time

For example for connecting to single peer we will be using this

```
    var conn = peer.connect(peerId);

    conn.on('open', function() {
        connect(conn);
    });
```

When i want to connect to multiple peer ID

For ex : var peerIDs = [ 'peerid 1',  'peerid 2', 'peerid 3']

I am using loop for this

```
for(var i=0 ; i < peerIDs.length ; i++){
    conn = peer.connect(peerIDs[i]);

    conn.on('open', function() {
        connect(conn);
    });        
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
var userId = new Date().getTime();
//Get the ID from the server
var peer   = new Peer(userId, {host: 'localhost', port: 3031, path: '/',debug: true }); 

var conn;
var connections = [];

//to receive id from the server
peer.on('open', function(id){
    console.log('the id is'  +id);

});

//in case of error
peer.on('error', function(e){
    alert(e.message);
})

//Awaits for the connection
peer.on('connection', connect);

function connect(c){

    conn = c;

    connections[c.peer].on('data', function(data){

        var mess = document.createElement('div');
        mess.innerHTML = '<span class="peer">' + c.peer + '</span>: ' + data;
        angular.element( document.querySelector( '.messages' ) ).append(mess);


    });

    connections[c.peer].on('close', function(){

        alert(c.peer + 'has left the chat');

    });



}

//When user clicks the chat button
$scope.chat = function(){
    alert('user clicked the connect button');

    var peerIDs = [ 'peerid 1',  'peerid 2', 'peerid 3'] 
    for(var i=0 ; i < peerIDs.length ; i++){
        var conn = peer.connect(peerIDs[i]);

        conn.on('open', function() {
            connections.push(c);
            connect(conn);
        });        
    }


}

//send message  when clicked
$scope.send = function(){

    // For each active connection, send the message.
    var msg = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#mess' ) ).val();

    //Send message to all connected peers
    for(var i in connections){
        connections[i].send(msg);
    }

    angular.element( document.querySelector( '.messages' ) ).append('<div><span class="you">You: </span>' + msg
          + '</div>');

}
```

Can you please give the insight of how to achieve this.Your help will be Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to have multi-connections at the same time, you just need to handle multi-connections at the same time.

```
// Array of remote peers ID and data channel
var remotePeerIds=[],// You need this to link with specific DOM element
connections=[]; // This is where you manage multi-connections

// create a Peer
var peer = new Peer({key: 'YOUR_KEY'}); // You can use your own peerID here

// Get your local peer id
peer.on('open', function(id) {
  console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
});

// Start connection with other peer - and handle it
getConnect(remotePeerId){
    var conn = peer.connect(remotePeerId);
    handleConnection(conn);
}

// Ok now you need to handle the received connection too
peer.on('connection',function(conn){
     handleConnection(conn);
});

// Handle connection - this is most important part
handleConnection(conn){
    remotePeerIds.push(conn.peer); // Add remote peer to list

    conn.on('open', function() {
        console.log("Connected with peer: "+remotePeerId);
        conn.on('data',function(data){
           // You can do whatever you want with the data from this connection - this is also the main part
           dataHandler(conn,data);
        });
        conn.on('error',function(){
          // handle error 
          connectionError(conn);
        });

        conn.on('close',function(){
          // Handle connection closed
          connectionClose(conn);
        });
        connections.push(conn);
    });
  });
}

// So now you have multi-connections. If you want to send a message to all other peer, just using for loop with all the connections
function broadcastMessage(message){
    for(var i=0;i<connections.length,i++){
        connections[i].send(message);
    }
}

// Or if you want to send a message to a specific peer - you need to know his peerid

function privateMessage(remotePeerId,message){
   for(var i=0;i<connections.length,i++){
        if(connections[i].peer==remotePeerId){
           connections[i].send(message);
           break;
        }
   }
}
```

This is the main part, you need to add some more code for connection handler in case of error and close.

That's it !

Comment: `remotePeerIds` The most important you did not specify.How to use this array ?

Answer (score 1):

@luongnv89 Thanks for your response.

But i am getting problem when i try to connect multiple peerID

For Ex :

```
    // Start connection with other peer - and handle it
    function getConnect(remotePeerId){
        var conn = peer.connect(remotePeerId);
        handleConnection(conn);
    } 

    var peerIDS = ['cttgmy43jy30udi0', 'mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr'];

    for(var i=0 ; i < peerIDS.length ; i++){
        getConnect(peerIDS[i]);     
    }
```

When i ran the above loop i can able to connect with only the last peerid which i pass in the array in this case it is 'mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr'

Here i post the console thing

```
PeerJS:  Creating RTCPeerConnection.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for ICE candidates.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for `negotiationneeded`
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for data channel
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for remote stream
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Creating RTCPeerConnection.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for ICE candidates.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for `negotiationneeded`
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for data channel
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for remote stream
2peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  `negotiationneeded` triggered
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Created offer.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Set localDescription: offer for: cttgmy43jy30udi0
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Created offer.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for: cttgmy43jy30udi0
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Set localDescription: offer for: mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for: mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Setting remote description RTCSessionDescription {sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 8190108536299128797 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s…id:data
↵a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
↵", type: "answer"}
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Added ICE candidate for: cttgmy43jy30udi0
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Set remoteDescription: ANSWER for: cttgmy43jy30udi0
2peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Added ICE candidate for: cttgmy43jy30udi0
2peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for: mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Data channel connection success
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Setting remote description RTCSessionDescription {sdp: "v=0
↵o=Mozilla-SIPUA-35.0.1 15417 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0…ap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
↵a=setup:active
↵", type: "answer"}
2peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Added ICE candidate for: mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Set remoteDescription: ANSWER for: mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Added ICE candidate for: mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Data channel connection success
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Added ICE candidate for: mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr
```

So what did is to make it work i dont know whether it is the right approach or not...

I just set the delay between connections

```
var peerIDS   = ['cttgmy43jy30udi0', 'mhzqhpn8rj4f5hfr'];
var arrLength = peerIDS.length;
var count     = 0;

(function processConnection(){

    if(arrLength <= count) return;

    getConnect(peerIDS[count]);
    count++;
    setTimeout(function(){
        processConnection()
    }, 5000);
})();
```

And now it is working properly..Can you please tell me whether i am going in a right path or is there anyother better way to accomplish this

Comment: I think using fix array of peerIDS is not a good idea. You can create an input box on your page to enter the remote peerId + "call" button. Whenever you have new remote peer to connect, just enter the peerID and click the button.
Btw, I don't have to set delay time as you did, still can call connect to many other peer at the same time :D.

Comment: @ luongnv89 : Array of PeerIDs is my project requirement.Actually Ever user who is online has a peerID and their peerID through socket it will be stored in the server.Suppose if i want to cal a person who is logged in both mobile and web i will be having two peerID  to connect right, that is what the array.If you have any other way to improve this please do share with me.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, you will have two peerIDs for mobile and web in this case. But you also have to manage to avoid you have two different remote peers, like you have both video from mobile and from web of only one remote peer.
Ok, from the log I think you already have two connections to two peers. You can check in browser console: peer.connections to list all the connections you have. And make sure that when you make the call, the 2 remote peer id should be online.